# Why newValues overwrites over oldValues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I have this weird bug in my React application. I have two google maps component, which should open maps with different locations but my problem is that both opens with the value of new location, which is the second google map. so First map should have the oldValue and second one should have the newValue but both have the same. I think there is a problem in `normalizeChangesHistory` function.
Here is the code of `normalizeChangesHistory` :

```
export const normalizeChangesHistory = (changesHistory: IChangeItem[]) => {
  const newValues: INormalizedChangeItem[] = []
  const oldValues: INormalizedChangeItem[] = []

  changesHistory.forEach((changeHistory: IChangeItem) => {
    newValues.push({
      field: changeHistory.field,
      value: changeHistory.newValue || "",
      type: getType(changeHistory.type),
      typeId: changeHistory.type,
    })
    oldValues.push({
      field: changeHistory.field,
      value: changeHistory.oldValue || "",
      type: getType(changeHistory.type),
      typeId: changeHistory.type,
    })
  })

  return { newValues, oldValues }
}
```

This is the file where I actually use these values in `<ChangeList />` component:

```
const { newValues, oldValues } = normalizeChangesHistory(changesHistory)

 <Flex padding="0 24px" width={"100%"} gap={"31px"} justifyContent="space-between">
                    <ChangeList items={oldValues} title={T("laundry.changes_history.current")} isCurrent={false} />
                    <ChangeList items={newValues} title={T("laundry.changes_history.required_updates")} isCurrent={true} />
                </Flex>
```

also if I change places of these two `<ChangeList />` components both of them have **oldValues**. Basically, both of them will have the value of **component**, which is written last. In this case `<ChangeList />` with the `items={newValues}`.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: might be a rendering issue ,you can set a state to monitor both the newValues and oldvalues

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to set a state to monitor both the newValues and oldValues please ?

Comment: What is `<ChangeList>` doing with the items? maybe it feeds the items into a kind of singleton datastructure like a store (and the last one to do so wins)?

Comment: before that make sure that  newValues, oldValues having distinct values console.log("Final result:", { newValues, oldValues });

Comment: @Martin  `<ChangeList>` is a component where it sorts out what kind of data should be provided. It can be price of something, name, or even location. Every other thing works well except location. On the left side of the page there is vertically list of old values, and on the right side there is list of new values. I can provide the code of `<ChangeList>` . Sorry if I couldn't answer well to your question.

Comment: @NodeDeveloper I have logged them and they have different values respectively.

Comment: @nika You can try to narrow down the problem by cutting out potential problem sources: if you replace the two `<ChangeList />` elements temporarily with something like `<div> old: {oldValues.toString()} <br/> new: {newValues.toString()}</div>` and the problem is still visible, you know that it has nothing to do with the `ChangeList` implementation. and vice versa.